# SSH timeout over remote login inspite of ServerAliveInterval / nohup

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

For reasons beyond my control, I have a setup like this:

Local: `script1.sh`, which calls `script2.sh` on the remote server on Wikitech over ssh, and then waits for the `script2.sh` to finish

Remote: `script2.sh`, which executes an SQL query on the Wikidb and writes the result into a file "file.txt".

Inside my local script1.sh, I have:

```
nohup ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1000 user@remote "path/to/script2.sh $ARG1 $ARG2 $FILENAME"
```

Inside my remote script2.sh, I have a query which takes a LONG, LONG time to execute. Think hours. I don't have much leeway to optimize the query much.

```
nohup sql enwiki "$QUERY">$FILENAME
```

After the query in script2.sh executes, the output is redirected to "file.txt".
`script1.sh`, which was waiting for this file, then sftps the "file.txt" down to local, and sends it for processing downstream.

The whole thing keeps breaking down with a `Write failed: Broken pipe` error in "nohup.out" on the local shell.

I had put in the `nohup`s and the `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to try and fix the problem, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

The remote files have nothing written them, if they are created at all.

Please help?

Comment: Do you also have to run the current system process `ssh -o ...` under nohup?

Comment: @anishsane I don't know for sure, but I thought that putting it in nohup separate out the ssh connection from the parent, and "protect" it in case the terminal was closed, or crashed, or something. I thought it might work for timeouts, but it didn't.

Comment: Why keep the connection open at all?  Just ssh to remote, launch script2.sh in the background with nohup, and exit.  Then a few hours later check back in to see if script2.sh has finished yet (i.e. by seeing if the output file exists).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should redirect output of following line too:

```
nohup ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1000 user@remote "path/to/script2.sh $ARG1 $ARG2 $FILENAME" &>out.log
```

if it won't help, execute script with `bash -x` so we could catch exactly where the problem occurred